# Puppy eating food, covered with hair, problem?

Tags: health, diet, puppy, shedding

My puppy will sometimes refuse to eat his food and dump it in his crate. So every once in a while I'll pull out his tray and let him eat it. But as he got older he has shed more. Now the trays are covered in hair more than food. He still eats it, but will it hurt him?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: No, very unlikely.

Remember wild carnivores (like wolves) will inevitable end up eating bits and pieces of their prey, including hair (and even bones). And don't forget about their own hair during cleaning.

Excessive amounts of hair can upset a dog's stomach (and theoretically even cause clogging), but these are typically vomited back out, if not at least partially digested.

Overall I'd say it's unlikely to cause any harm from your description. (How do you define "covered" here? 4-5 hairs?) If you still worry, occasionally add a few dips of (fish) oil to food you know the dog will eat without tossing around or storing (to avoid stains). Just keep in mind this might cause diarrhea, if you're adding too much. But on the plus side it will help with shedding and the fur's health overall.

If you think your dog is losing an excessive/too massive amount of hair, talk about it with your vet.